# 'Console.log/error/warn' for the client side is overwritten in my app and I don't know where. Possibly 'winston' npm package.

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Our app is running on three different environments- dev, stage and production.

When I print to the browser console with console.log in a development env (npm proxy) I see my prints.

When I print in staging and production there is no output. Looking in the source code on the browser.  'console.*' simply does not appear where it should and of course nothing is printed to the console.

All the environments use node.js as their server environment. In addition we use npm  'winston' package that logs servers 'logger.* to a specific folder.

Prints on the server side works fine.

I'v been searching through our code "console =', 'window.console =', 'console.log='. I'd also searched for for code that differs the different environments but I didn't find any code overwriting the 'console'.

We also using 'ngnix' and a load balancer.

Any idea will be most welcome.

Comment: `winston` doesn't deal with client-side code. Are you using a bundler like Webpack or Browserify, or something like UglifyJS?

Comment: Yea I do use Browserify and UglifyJS. I'm gonna take a look there thanks for the hint. If you can focus me even more will be great too.

Answer (score 0):

So what solve it for me is changing in Gruntfile.js the field

'drop_console' from true to false.

Was caused do to the uglify package.

Thanks to @robertklep.